# Display a .db file (sqlite3) with sql.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sqlite, sql.js

I'm new to JavaScript. 
I'm actually trying to read a .db file using the sql.js (https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/), without using any server.

I just want to have 'local' html/js files that will display my database without using any server. For this project, I'm using AngularJS/HTML5/CSS3, and node.js just for testing my app.

But I'm really lost, can someone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add more details about your problem and your own efforts this far to solve the problem so that people can help you better. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For the moment I've tried all the solutions listed on the different GitHub issues, but I just can't import this database and display it on my web app.

I'am trying to do a 'local website', where I'll can see my database into a table, and use some filters.
I'm not asking for a solution, just some tips, I really don't know how to create a local website in these languages, how to import a local .db file, how should I display it...